# Clang failed with exit code 254 while converting non-ARC project to Objective-C ARC using XCode

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to converting a non-ARC project ( https://github.com/allaboutapps/A3GridTableView ) to ARC using the XCode ARC Converter.
I am getting the following error

**Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 254**.

I followed the scenario 1 of the http://maniacdev.com/2012/01/easily-get-non-arc-enabled-open-source-libraries-working-in-arc-enabled-projects/ tutorial.

I am using XCode Version 4.5.2 with Apple LLVM compiler 4.1.

I tried to google the error but couldn't relate it to my case.
Thanks in advance.

The entire error output is

```
CompileC /Users/mihirrege/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A3GridTableViewSample-azjqesubssdefeedzlssseklompv/Build/Intermediates/A3GridTableViewSample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/A3GridTableViewSample.build/Objects-normal/i386/A3GridTableView.o A3GridTableView/A3GridTableView.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/mihirrege/Downloads/A3GridTableView-master
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -ccc-arcmt-check -mios-simulator-version-min=5.1 -iquote /Users/mihirrege/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A3GridTableViewSample-azjqesubssdefeedzlssseklompv/Build/Intermediates/A3GridTableViewSample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/A3GridTableViewSample.build/A3GridTableViewSample-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/mihirrege/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A3GridTableViewSample-azjqesubssdefeedzlssseklompv/Build/Intermediates/A3GridTableViewSample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/A3GridTableViewSample.build/A3GridTableViewSample-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/mihirrege/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A3GridTableViewSample-azjqesubssdefeedzlssseklompv/Build/Intermediates/A3GridTableViewSample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/A3GridTableViewSample.build/A3GridTableViewSample-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/mihirrege/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A3GridTableViewSample-azjqesubssdefeedzlssseklompv/Build/Intermediates/A3GridTableViewSample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/A3GridTableViewSample.build/A3GridTableViewSample-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/mihirrege/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A3GridTableViewSample-azjqesubssdefeedzlssseklompv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/mihirrege/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A3GridTableViewSample-azjqesubssdefeedzlssseklompv/Build/Intermediates/A3GridTableViewSample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/A3GridTableViewSample.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/mihirrege/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A3GridTableViewSample-azjqesubssdefeedzlssseklompv/Build/Intermediates/A3GridTableViewSample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/A3GridTableViewSample.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/mihirrege/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A3GridTableViewSample-azjqesubssdefeedzlssseklompv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -include /Users/mihirrege/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A3GridTableViewSample-azjqesubssdefeedzlssseklompv/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/A3GridTableViewSample-Prefix-exjedgarwqkaqyfxqduaqwpafmyv/A3GridTableViewSample-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/mihirrege/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A3GridTableViewSample-azjqesubssdefeedzlssseklompv/Build/Intermediates/A3GridTableViewSample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/A3GridTableViewSample.build/Objects-normal/i386/A3GridTableView.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/mihirrege/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A3GridTableViewSample-azjqesubssdefeedzlssseklompv/Build/Intermediates/A3GridTableViewSample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/A3GridTableViewSample.build/Objects-normal/i386/A3GridTableView.dia -c /Users/mihirrege/Downloads/A3GridTableView-master/A3GridTableView/A3GridTableView.m -o /Users/mihirrege/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A3GridTableViewSample-azjqesubssdefeedzlssseklompv/Build/Intermediates/A3GridTableViewSample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/A3GridTableViewSample.build/Objects-normal/i386/A3GridTableView.o

0  clang             0x0000000101058eb2 main + 17130418
1  clang             0x0000000101059339 main + 17131577
2  libsystem_c.dylib 0x00007fff8e4098ea _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_c.dylib 0x0000000101cadf80 _sigtramp + 18446603342454605488
4  clang             0x00000001005a60df main + 5912031
5  clang             0x0000000100c99793 main + 13200531
6  clang             0x0000000100a76270 main + 10958704
7  clang             0x0000000100b6d7ff main + 11971839
8  clang             0x0000000100b1ffbe main + 11654334
9  clang             0x0000000100b8e74c main + 12106828
10 clang             0x0000000100b900c1 main + 12113345
11 clang             0x0000000100b907dc main + 12115164
12 clang             0x0000000100a76c11 main + 10961169
13 clang             0x0000000100a791f9 main + 10970873
14 clang             0x00000001000211e5 main + 124645
15 clang             0x00000001000199d6 main + 93910
16 clang             0x0000000100018648 main + 88904
17 clang             0x0000000100006308 main + 14344
18 clang             0x0000000100002d87 main + 647
19 clang             0x0000000100002af4
Stack dump:



0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -cc1 -triple i386-apple-ios5.1.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name A3GridTableView.m -pic-level 1 -mdisable-fp-elim -relaxed-aliasing -masm-verbose -target-cpu yonah -target-linker-version 134.9 -coverage-file /Users/mihirrege/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A3GridTableViewSample-azjqesubssdefeedzlssseklompv/Build/Intermediates/A3GridTableViewSample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/A3GridTableViewSample.build/Objects-normal/i386/A3GridTableView.o -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/4.1 -arcmt-check -dependency-file /Users/mihirrege/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A3GridTableViewSample-azjqesubssdefeedzlssseklompv/Build/Intermediates/A3GridTableViewSample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/A3GridTableViewSample.build/Objects-normal/i386/A3GridTableView.d -MT dependencies -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -iquote /Users/mihirrege/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A3GridTableViewSample-azjqesubssdefeedzlssseklompv/Build/Intermediates/A3GridTableViewSample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/A3GridTableViewSample.build/A3GridTableViewSample-generated-files.hmap -iquote /Users/mihirrege/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A3GridTableViewSample-azjqesubssdefeedzlssseklompv/Build/Intermediates/A3GridTableViewSample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/A3GridTableViewSample.build/A3GridTableViewSample-project-headers.hmap -include-pch /Users/mihirrege/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A3GridTableViewSample-azjqesubssdefeedzlssseklompv/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/A3GridTableViewSample-Prefix-exjedgarwqkaqyfxqduaqwpafmyv/A3GridTableViewSample-Prefix.pch.pth -D DEBUG=1 -D IBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet)) -D IBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName))) -D IBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction) -I /Users/mihirrege/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A3GridTableViewSample-azjqesubssdefeedzlssseklompv/Build/Intermediates/A3GridTableViewSample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/A3GridTableViewSample.build/A3GridTableViewSample-own-target-headers.hmap -I /Users/mihirrege/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A3GridTableViewSample-azjqesubssdefeedzlssseklompv/Build/Intermediates/A3GridTableViewSample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/A3GridTableViewSample.build/A3GridTableViewSample-all-target-headers.hmap -I /Users/mihirrege/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A3GridTableViewSample-azjqesubssdefeedzlssseklompv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I /Users/mihirrege/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A3GridTableViewSample-azjqesubssdefeedzlssseklompv/Build/Intermediates/A3GridTableViewSample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/A3GridTableViewSample.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I /Users/mihirrege/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A3GridTableViewSample-azjqesubssdefeedzlssseklompv/Build/Intermediates/A3GridTableViewSample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/A3GridTableViewSample.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/mihirrege/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A3GridTableViewSample-azjqesubssdefeedzlssseklompv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -fmodule-cache-path /var/folders/j3/t6t3fgr52szcn945c3jn261c0000gn/T/clang-module-cache -O0 -Wno-trigraphs -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-sign-conversion -std=gnu99 -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-runtime-has-arc -fobjc-runtime-has-weak -fobjc-runtime-has-terminate -fobjc-default-synthesize-properties -fobjc-exceptions -fexceptions -fpascal-strings -fdiagnostics-show-option -serialize-diagnostic-file /Users/mihirrege/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A3GridTableViewSample-azjqesubssdefeedzlssseklompv/Build/Intermediates/A3GridTableViewSample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/A3GridTableViewSample.build/Objects-normal/i386/A3GridTableView.dia -o /Users/mihirrege/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A3GridTableViewSample-azjqesubssdefeedzlssseklompv/Build/Intermediates/A3GridTableViewSample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/A3GridTableViewSample.build/Objects-normal/i386/A3GridTableView.o -x objective-c /Users/mihirrege/Downloads/A3GridTableView-master/A3GridTableView/A3GridTableView.m 
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: i386-apple-darwin12.2.0
Thread model: posix
clang: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Error generating preprocessed source(s).
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 254
```

Comment: Ermahgherd you broke CLANG... Naw, it's just a segfault.  Clear out your build folder and try again

Comment: well first off i suggest submitting a bug report, as for the crash, I have never seen this and think it is hilarious. has the project changed at all? meaning did it convert any of the project?

Comment: @DanZimm No. It didnt convert any of the project, while trying to convert it gives the error:  Xcode found 1 issue that prevents conversion from proceeding.  Fix all ARC readiness issues and try again.

Comment: @CodaFi I cleared the build folder, same error again. By build folder I am assuming the derived data folder.

Comment: You should not ignore the warnings CLANG is outputting.  ARC conversion does not proceed without a clean build.

Comment: have you tried looking here and following this? http://www.daveoncode.com/2011/10/24/migration-to-arc-automatic-reference-counting-using-xcode-4-2-refactor/

Comment: @CodaFi I am unable to comprehend the warnings CLANG is outputting.

Comment: @DanZimm Yes. I did. But the issues I am getting after the step 5 mentioned is the following error, which I am unable to fix.

Comment: Well what's the error (besides this) that it produces?

Comment: if you did the precheck then it should tell you exactly why it fails, are you sure you clicked precheck? and if so are you sure there is no other information being spit out?

Comment: @DanZimm In my version of XCode, there is no "precheck" option, its simply "check". I did that and the information I supplied ( the error) is all it spit out.

Comment: did you do "1. “Preferences” -> “General” -> check “continue building after error”" ?

Comment: @DanZimm Yes. I did that

Comment: yea sorry mate best advice would be go and report the bug

Comment: The title says exit code **256** and the post says exit code **254**, which is the good one?

Comment: @Zaphod 254, sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue. In your case, adding `@synthesize dataSource = _dataSource` in `A3GridTableView.m` should help.

`[A3GridTableView setDataSource:]` has a memory management bug in it which is somehow related to this clang crash.